# Querying using multiple databases (connections) in dbeaver

Tags: multiple-databases, dbeaver

I want to access multiple databases(multiple connections) at once in dbeaver and to the SQL querying.
As an example, I have 3 data connections: A, B and C.

I want to run a query like this:

```
select * from A
left join B on A.column=B.column
left join C on A.column=C.column
```

Is this not allowed in dbeaver?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for anyone who else who lands here one answer is to use database level tools. For Postgres you can use something like [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html) (see [dblink_connect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/contrib-dblink-connect.html) as well)

```sql
SELECT dblink_connect('conn_name', 'connection string');

WITH remote as (SELECT * FROM dblink('conn_name', 'query')
SELECT * FROM local_table
JOIN remote ON local_table.column = remote.column
```

Answer (score -1):

No. You need a Data Virtualization or Data Integration tool.